# inserting reservation to database

Tags: mysql, database

This has been driving me crazy and I'm sure it's something simple. I'm getting a 'values must contain at least one element' error from server when I try to input a reservation from the table that comes up.  It's all running ok. No matter if I use quotes in the VALUES section or plus(+)symbols or quotes over the separating commas I get different error messages. When I put quotes over table_num I get and error telling me that you cant insert CHAR into INTEGER. When I remove quotes I get error telling me - 
Severe:   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'TABLE_NUM' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification etc. Could anyone tell me what is going on? Here's the jsp code. Thanks in advance.

```
        <%    
            int tableNum = 0; 
            String firstName = null; 
            String lastName = null;
            String Address = null;
            int Phone = 0;
            java.sql.Date date = null;
            int People = 0;

            if (request.getParameter("table_num")!=null){
                tableNum = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("table_num"));
            }
            if (request.getParameter("first")!=null){
                firstName = request.getParameter("first");
            }
            if (request.getParameter("last")!=null){
                lastName = request.getParameter("last");
            }
            if (request.getParameter("address")!=null){
                Address = request.getParameter("address");
            }
            if (request.getParameter("phone")!=null){
                Phone = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("phone"));
            }
            if (request.getParameter("date")!=null){
               java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date(request.getParameter("date"));
               date = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime()); 
            }
            if (request.getParameter("people")!=null){
                People = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("people"));
            }
            if(tableNum != 0 && firstName != null && lastName != null && Address != null && Phone != 0 && date != null && People != 0){ 
                String URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Reservations";  
                String USERNAME= "johnpaul";
                String PASSWORD= "purlease";
                Connection myCon = null;
                Statement ste = null;
                PreparedStatement preparedStmt = null;

                try{
                    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"); 
                    System.out.println("Connecting to DB...");
                    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Reservations","johnpaul", "purlease");
                    System.out.println("Connected successfuly");

                    System.out.println("Inserting records into table");      
                    Statement st = con.createStatement();
                    String query = "INSERT INTO JOHNPAUL.CUSTOMER_RESERVATIONS(TABLE_NUM,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,TELEPHONE,DATE,NUMBER_IN_PARTY)VALUES(table_num,first,last,address,phone,date,people)";


                    st.executeUpdate (query);  
                    System.out.println("Records inserted");


                   }catch(SQLException se){
                    se.printStackTrace();
                }catch(ClassNotFoundException se){
            //Handle errors for JDBC
                    se.printStackTrace();
            }catch(Exception e){
                //Handle errors for Class.forName
                     e.printStackTrace(); 

            }
            }            
         %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be here:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO JOHNPAUL.CUSTOMER_RESERVATIONS 
    (TABLE_NUM, FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,TELEPHONE, DATE, NUMBER_IN_PARTY)
    VALUES (table_num, first,last,address,phone,date,people)";
```

Two things here: 
 1. Escape your strings; and
 2. Concatenate the values in your variables to the string.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO JOHNPAUL.CUSTOMER_RESERVATIONS 
        (TABLE_NUM, FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,TELEPHONE, DATE, NUMBER_IN_PARTY)
        VALUES (" + table_num + ", '" + first + "', '" + last + "', '" + address + "', " + phone + " , '" + date + "', " + people + ");";
```

You may have to verify the format that your database engine expects the date field.

Comment: Thanks Lee. I got it sorted. Just having problem with date now. All works well when I remove all ref to date in jsp code and records are inserted into DB. Bur getting error message telling me  - 'Columns of type 'DATE' cannot hold values of type 'INTEGER'' when leaving all the date coding in.